# Why does the new Integer act as value type int?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String []args){ 
  Integer a = new Integer(9);
  d(a);
  System.out.print(a) ;
}

public static void d(int z){
  z=z+2; 
}
```

or suppose I write

```
public static void main(String []args){
  int a = 9;
  d(a);
  System.out.print(a) ;
}

public static void d(int z){
  z=z+2; 
}
```

but the output is the same for both: `9`. Can anyone explain me in detail why?

Comment: Read about auto-boxing of primitive types

Comment: This is called [autoboxing and unboxing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autoboxing-unboxing-java/) in Java. The `Integer`-object is autoboxed to a primitive `int`.

Comment: [Autoboxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Why would you want these two programs to give out different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code with `Integer` a process called unboxing occurs. The `Integer`-instance is unboxed to a primitive `int` when calling your method `d`. [See this to better understand how autoboxing and unboxing works.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autoboxing-unboxing-java/)

As for your `z=z+2` inside the method `d`. Java objects are passed-by-reference, but Java primitives or Immutable objects (like Strings) are passed-by-value. Since your method `d` has a primitive parameter `int` it's passed-by-value in this case. Your `z=z+2` isn't returned however.

If you would add `System.out.println(z);` right after `z=z+2` it will indeed print `11`. So why isn't the `a` in your `main`-method changed to `11` and how can you accomplish this? As I mentioned, it's passed-by-value for primitives. You'll need to return the new value and set the `a` in the main method with it. If you change your code to this it will work:

```
public static void main(String []args){
  int a = 9;
  a = d(a);
  System.out.print(a);
}

public static int d(int z){
  return z+2; 
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZU09D4IwEN35FW8sMTK4GeJPcGI0DiclpAiF9K4kYPjttUU2l3v38r46munc6XcIdU/MuJOxnwyY/Ks3NVhIIsyj0RiipCpxxrZ4PMm1nCcnYKyAcMO13Gl6taL8x6qFpRmK0Usxxagcwpb9jaQardJdj2LXiHcW6@lSYs9sIXwB)

As you can see, the `void d` is changed to `int d`, and we return the result of `z+2`. We then overwrite the value of `a` with this new result with `a = d(a);` in the `main`-method.

Answer (score 1):

Because JAVA is PASS BY VALUE not PASS BY REFERENCE.

Let us understand it this way,

Your main function has a local variable z whose scope is limited to main only

and your d function has another local variable z whose scope is limited to d only

So, in your d fucntion, you are basically creating a new integer literal 11 and putting it to local variable z whose scope is limited to d function only and not the variable z of main.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a concept of AutoBoxing and Auto unboxing for primitive datatypes.
Since primitves like int, float double, long etc are technically not objects, they have their corresponding Classes which can be instantiated with the primitive value to treat them as objects.

So to reduce the pain, java automatically converts int to Integer and Integer to int where ever applicable.

If you are wondering why the addition value has not reflected, though it is an Integer object on performing addition, a new int object will be resulted. so it wont reflect directly. You can return the value from the method you call and assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

Java passes variables by value, not by reference. If you think that passing an object and changing the value of its data member would work, it won't. In that case, too, a copy of that object will be passed, not the original object. The only solution is to declare the variable as static that can be changed from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

it's all because of Autoboxing and Unboxing feature of java which provide the functionality of converting primitive to object(Wrapper) type and vice-versa. for better understanding you can check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)
. I hope it will clear all your doubts.